# JPA SQLSyntax missing expression error

Tags: java, jpa

I have a Java EE application that has a named Query in an entity called download.
The named query is:

```
 @NamedQuery(name="Users.DownloadCount",
            query="SELECT u.fullName, count(u.downloads) FROM WebUser u "
                    + "JOIN u.downloads ud WHERE ud.downloadTime "
                    + "> :startDate AND ud.downloadTime < :endDate")
```

I attempt to do the following query in one of my methods:

```
List<Object[]> downloads = new ArrayList();
        if(userName==null){
             downloads = manager.createNamedQuery("Users.DownloadCount").setParameter("startDate", sDate,TemporalType.DATE)
                                                                        .setParameter("endDate", eDate,TemporalType.DATE).getResultList();
```

The date variables sDate and eDate are:

```
 Date sDate = format.parse(startDate);
 Date eDate = format.parse(endDate);
```

For some reason however I seem to be getting a :

```
java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00936: missing expression
```

exception.

I have pulled the query out of the entity class and done a normal entitymanager query call but I still get the same exception.

Comment: please add a blank between "ud.downloadTime" and ""> :s" and between "ud.downloadTime" and "<" !

Comment: so what SQL is generated? You can't expect people to guess when you have the info in your log

Comment: @NeilStockton I Would like to but the eclipse link logging for wildfly 10 CR4 isn't working for me so I am unable to do so. I have however realised my mistakes and posted them as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I realised the problem:

First problem: Missing a group by with the aggregate function

Second problem: Not joining the entities WebUser and Downloads so no way for the function to count the amount of related entities.

Query should be:

```
"SELECT u.fullName, count(d) FROM WebUser u JOIN u.downloads d "
                    + "WHERE d.downloadTime > :startDate AND d.downloadTime< :endDate"
                    + " GROUP BY u.fullName"
```

Answer (score 1):

Add a blank between `ud.downloadTime` and `> :s` and between `ud.downloadTime` and `<` !

Comment: Is the error gone if you delete your where condition? just to check where the error is ...

Comment: yes, it's definitely something to do with the dates.

Comment: sorry, can't help you. but perhaps you find your answer there:  http://blog.jooq.org/2014/12/29/leaky-abstractions-or-how-to-bind-oracle-date-correctly-with-hibernate/

Comment: try use between construction: `ud.downloadTime BETWEEN :startDate AND :endDate`